# Difference between adding object and attaching it using MoveIt?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am following the
[MoveIT Python tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/move_group_python_interface/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html)

According to the tutorial, we can add an object and attach it later.
However I did not understand what is the difference between adding and attaching an object.

For example; I added an object firstly as I showed in the following picture. MoveIt detects the collision and I cannot close the gripper.

[image: image description]

If I add the object and attach it (to the world frame ), robot exhibits the same behavior.

[image: image description]

**So what is the difference between adding object and attaching it ?**

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368526/difference-between-adding-object-and-attaching-it-using-moveit-?/) by [erdisayar](https://answers.ros.org/users/66260/erdisayar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you *add* a `CollisionObject` to the planning scene, it exists as a stationary object in the scene that the robot can collide with. When you *attach* a `CollisionObject`, it moves with the robot link that it is attached to.

In your case, you placed your object at a position where it collides with the robot. You could change the object's position, or allow collision with the robot gripper link. The latter is more useful if you want to grasp the object.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erdisayar](https://answers.ros.org/users/66260/erdisayar/) on 2021-01-08**:
If I attach the object in a stationary frame (/world), Then can we say that there is no difference between attaching an object to the stationary frame or adding object in scene without attaching it?

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-01-09**:
Yes, currently there is no meaningful difference. If you publish a `CollisionObject` to the planning scene, the object is by default stationary in the planning frame (`world`), and attaching an object to a fixed frame is equivalent.